# Debian boot problem

Tags: boot, debian, debian-squeeze

I have installed Slackware on /dev/sda6 and lilo at MBR, after that I installed Debian Squeeze beta2 on /dev/sda7 and grub at first section of /dev/sda7, I added at /etc/lilo.conf record for debian ( I was doing this with other versions of Debian and it worked ), but when I try to enter to Debain I got error message

> First sector of /dev/sda7 doesn't have
>   a valid boot signature

Can anybody help ?

---

@Gilles
fdisk -l

> Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016
>   bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track,
>   30401 cylinders Units = cylinders of
>   16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes Sector
>   size (logical/physical): 512 bytes /
>   512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal):
>   512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier:
>   0x00e20a72
>
> Device Boot      Start         End 
>   Blocks   Id  System /dev/sda1
>   1          13      102400    7 
>   HPFS/NTFS Partition 1 does not end on
>   cylinder boundary. /dev/sda2
>   13        5100    40861696    7 
>   HPFS/NTFS /dev/sda3            5101
>   30401   203222379+   5  Extended
>   /dev/sda5            5101       14826 
>   78124063+   7  HPFS/NTFS /dev/sda6
>   14827       22699    63232000   83 
>   Linux /dev/sda7   *       22699
>   30009    58716160   83  Linux
>   /dev/sda8           30009       30401 
>   3147776   82  Linux swap

Comment: It looks like you didn't actually install Grub there. How exactly did you install Grub? What version? What is the output of `fdisk -l`, and of `</dev/sda7 head -c 512 | hd`?

Comment: I install during instalation, there is options for that.